# Grouping the list elements into user defined intervals

Tags: python, histogram

```
def interval():
    data = [1, 2, 12, 13, 22, 23, 32, 33, 42, 43, 52, 53, 62, 63, 72, 73, 82, 83, 92, 93]
    minimum = raw_input("Enter the min value")
    maximum = raw_input("Enter the max value")
    frequency = raw_input("Enter the Freq")
    x = []
    x.append(float(minimum))
    thesum = float(minimum)
    for i in range(0, int(maximum)):
        if thesum < float(maximum):
            thesum = thesum + float(frequency)
            x.append(thesum)
    print x 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    interval()
```

**Assume the user enters the min, max and freq to be  0,100,20 respectively. 
So, the intervals are 0-20, 20-40,40-60,60-80,80-100 and my output should be

The values in 0-20 are [1,2,12,13]
The values in 20-40 are [22,23,32,33]
.. and so on! 
**

**If there are no values in a particular interval, the output should be list with no values**

Comment: Whats your question? and also `sum` is a reserved word , don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: tell some description like what you want and what is your expected out

Comment: Yes. Assume the min, max and freq are 0,100,20  respectively. So, My output should be something like 1,2,12,13 are the values in 0-20. 

And as you can clearly see the min, max and freq are user-defined and so is the data!  *The data is also generalized*

Comment: Is data guaranteed to be sorted?

Comment: Yes. And also , if there's no data in an interval, it should print 0.

Comment: This seems to be more of a homework assignment. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922).

Comment: pls edit your question with the comments you made to make it whole.

Comment: Also, it looks like only the values of `min` and `frequency` are important to find out what seems to be `values within the range of min-frequency` from the example you've given. Can you give more test cases. Where does the value `100` in max have a role here?

Comment: It's not a test assignment. You can be sure. Yes. I'll make the question whole!

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla 100 is just another user given value. It can be anything. You can go from -10(min) to 10000(max) in steps of 1(frequency).

Comment: Could someone help? Is it legit now?

Answer (score 1):

A very naive way to implement this would be as follows

```
def group_items(data, low_value, high_value):
    return [value for value in data if value >= low_value and value <= high_value]
```

This function returns the list of numbers that exist in the ranges `[min, max]` inclusive, therefore `max` will be accounted for in both `(min,max) and (min+freq, max+freq)` because `max` of first interval is `min+freq` of next interval. Of course you can correct this based on your requirements.

```
min_max_pairs = []
for x in xrange(minimum, maximum, frequency):
    pair = (x, x+frequency)
    min_max_pairs.append(pair)
```

This creates the map from the minimum to maximum values specified by the user using the frequency interval. In your case the values in min, max and freq are

```
minimum = raw_input("Enter the min value")
maximum = raw_input("Enter the max value")
frequency = raw_input("Enter the Freq")
```

This returns the pair as follows:

```
>>> min_max_pairs
[(0, 20), (20, 40), (40, 60), (60, 80), (80, 100)]
```

Now loop through the pairs and pass them to the `group_items()` to get the required result

```
for pair in min_max_pairs:
    min = pair[0]
    max = pair[1]
    interval = freq
    print ("Range [",min,"-",max,"] : ", group_items(data, min, max))
```

that results in

```
Range [ 0 - 20 ]:  [1, 2, 12, 13]
Range [ 20 - 40 ]:  [22, 23, 32, 33]
Range [ 40 - 60 ]:  [42, 43, 52, 53]
Range [ 60 - 80 ]:  [62, 63, 72, 73]
Range [ 80 - 100 ]:  [82, 83, 92, 93]
```

Comment: @Athreya Sridhar If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation points. If my question was actually worth your time, please give it an upvote!